# Fail to install Hackage string-conversions

Tags: haskell, installation, cabal, cabal-install, hackage

## Problem

I was installing the Hackage `string-conversions`. However, it fails with the error below.

## Error Log

```
Configuring string-conversions-0.3.0.3...
Building string-conversions-0.3.0.3...
Preprocessing library string-conversions-0.3.0.3...
[1 of 1] Compiling Data.String.Conversions ( Data/String/Conversions.hs, dist/build/Data/String/Conversions.o )
In-place registering string-conversions-0.3.0.3...
Creating package registration file:
/tmp/pkgConf-string-conversions-0.3.011675.3
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
string-conversions-0.3.0.3 failed during the final install step. The exception
was:
/tmp/pkgConf-string-conversions-0.3.011675.3: hGetContents: invalid argument
(invalid byte sequence)
```

## Environment

Ubuntu GNOME: 14.10

ghc: 7.6.3

cabal: 1.20.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally figured out the solution.

Rajarshi is right for the locale problem. However, changing the locale temporarily won't work.

The package now correctly installed after changing the locale permanently.

## How to check the current locale setting

1. `$ locale`
2. If you notice that `LANG` is `C` or empty, probably it is not configured correctly

## How to change the locale setting permanently (Ubuntu)

1. `$ sudo update-locale LANG=en_US-UTF-8`
2. Log out and log in again

## References

1. [Locale - Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale)

Answer (score 0):

This is a locale-related error. Check that `LANG` is set to `C.UTF-8`, `en_US.UTF-8`, or another `UTF-8 locale`. Check that locale files are available on the system.

you have to set `LANG=C.UTF-8` (use `locale -a` to see which ones are available on your system).

you can see more in
http://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/1883 it will help you

Comment: Does it mean to set `LANG` environment variable as `C.UTF-8`? i.e. `$ LANG=C.UTF-8`

Comment: what it gives after `locale -a`

Comment: `C
C.UTF-8
POSIX
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
`

Comment: where is `en_US.UTF8`

Comment: it is your locale issue not cabal

Comment: How should I fix it, Rajarshi?

Comment: please set it `LANG=en_US.UTF8`

Comment: string conversion required locale to translation

Comment: I have already tried `C.UTF-8`, `en_US.utf8` and `en_HK.utf8` but still no luck

Comment: it shoul work can you please try it? string converion installation

Comment: Yes, I even do `$ echo $LANG` to confirm before installation. Still the same error.

Comment: Already tried `C.UTF-8`, `C`, `en_US.utf8`, `en_US.UTF8`, `en_US.UTF-8`, `en_HK.utf8`.